# java-html-sanitizer replace elements not in whitelist with whitespace

Tags: java, html

I am using OWASP/java-html-sanitizer HtmlPolicyBuilder()           .allowElements() to sanitize elements in html.

If body is "<div>messageOne</div><div>messageTwo</div>" and <div> is not in whitelist, then after sanitization, it becomes "messageOnemessageTwo".

It is undesirable that two words become one word. Is there a way to use OWASP/java-html-sanitizer or any other java sanitizer to make it " messageOne messageTwo "(replace <div> with whitespace instead of just removing it)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was not able to find out how to do it with the OWASP Sanitiser

So I found a dirty way to achieve the objective.

Before passing the string to the OWASP Sanitiser I replaced all occurrences of ">" with "> ".

After calling OWASP Sanitiser I then replaced all occurrences of "  " with just " ".

As stated this works but is somewhat dirty so if someone has a cleaner solution would be great